# How to convert Java Pojo to Nashorn Json?

Tags: java, json, java-8, pojo, nashorn

I have a Java object that I want to turn into a json object and pass to the Nashorn javascript engine. It is surprisingly difficult to google an answer for this! Can someone tell me how to do it?

I tried this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String inputModelAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(inputModel);
```

And then passing the string json to the function:

```
result = invocable.invokeFunction(PROGRAM_FUNCTION, moduleName, inputModelAsString);
```

But it was passed as a string, not as a json.

Comment: You can parse the string in your javascript code with JSON.parse(s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert json from engine by

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
ScriptObjectMirror json = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval("("+inputModelAsString+")");
```

Then you can pass the json object in you code

```
result = invocable.invokeFunction(PROGRAM_FUNCTION, moduleName, json);
```

Comment: Tried it, but ScriptObjectMirror jsonInputModel = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval("{\"test\":1}"); results in a ScriptException. Its expecting a ';' where the ':' is. Good idea though, how do I get it to work?

Comment: For some reason you need to put brackets around the expression like this: engine.eval("("+inputModelAsString+")") Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and handled it in a slightly different way.

I wouldn't access the class ScriptObjectMirror directly as it's part of the internal Nashorn's API and therefore prone to change.

You may try something like this:

```
engine.eval("var inputModel = " + inputModel + ";");    
Object json = engine.get("inputModel");
```

Answer (score -2):

you could use inbuild JSON feature in Nashorn as mentioned in

[Nashorn JSON stringify](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91184/java-json-stringifier-with-the-nashorn-api)