# Get a proper JSON literal in Java 8 using nashorn

Tags: json, java-8, nashorn

I have a message that's to be sent over a socket, a string that represents a json:

`String message = "{\"sql\": \"{0}\"}";`

I use `MessageFormatter` to put in the actual message from the user, and send it to the server.

However, this needs to be a proper JSON string for the server to understand.

After dabbling with manual escaping, realizing the SQL message can have nested quotes and whatnot, I understand I want to use a proper JSON tool to make sure the string is json-correct.

I wish to use nashorn to keep the code vanilla and avoid baggage in the jar.

Nashorn seems quite capable and fit for the task, but I'm picking it up as I go, and I'm not sure what to do at this point.

I tried the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279892/how-to-convert-java-pojo-to-nashorn-json) :

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
ScriptObjectMirror json = (ScriptObjectMirror) engine.eval("JSON");
message = (String) json.callMember("stringify", json.callMember("parse", message));
```

However, this merely validates my string, I wish nashorn to actually escape it to a proper form.

- I am aware of Jackson.
- I am aware of other JSON libraries.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found is to pass the user string as a variable to the engine via `Bindings`.

Then you can stringify via `engine.eval("JSON.stringify()")`:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
Bindings bindings = engine.getContext().getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);
bindings.put("sql_from_user", sql);
String proper_json_message = (String) engine.eval("JSON.stringify({sql : sql_from_user})");
```